# Kivy without kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying for some time to put a wallpaper and widgets but I can not do both, if you have the answer please help me.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

kivy.require('2.0.0')

class MainMenu(App):

    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
        self.Background = FloatLayout()
        self.BackgroundImg = Image(source='icons/football_ground.jpg', allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
        self.Background.add_widget(self.BackgroundImg)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text=''))
        return self.Background


MainMenu().run()
```

Thanks for your futur answers

Comment: You never assign `layout` to anything, so no widgets are saved

Comment: Because, you have not added the `layout` to anything, try, `self.Background.add_widget(layout)`.